# how to create matrix of buttons having images dynamically in windows phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, imagebutton

I am new to Windows phone Application development. I am creating a Game.

My requirement for game is, like I want to create a **matrix of buttons** of 8x8 dimension which should be created dynamically and has to be handled through code only.Also I want to give image to button which is to be changed on button click.

Please help me as early as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML or XNA?

If you are using XAML, you can simply create 64 buttons using two loops and place them in grid. Simply define for each button its width, height and margins to position it inside parent grid.

If you are using XNA, again use two loops to generate 64 buttons and manually calculate the correct dimensions and positions for buttons.

Each button as its content can contain BitmapImage as well as an ordinary string.

```
var btn = new Button();
btn.Content = new BitmapImage("...");
```

---

Since I was asked again how to do it, I just wanted to the relevant code snippet here:

```
var rows = 5;
var columns = 6;

var grid = new Grid();

for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
        {
            Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        });

for (var i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        });

for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        var control = new Button();
        Grid.SetRow(control, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(control, j);
        grid.Children.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2257265: In XAML, consider using a UniformGrid to hold the buttons and help you with positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button txtf = new Button();
ImageBrush br=new ImageBrush();
 ImageBrush br=new ImageBrush();
br.ImageSource= new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/fb/FB.jpg" ,UriKind.Relative));
txtf.Background = br;
```

ok i think it will work fine try this 
Regards developer Muhammad Imran